# Convert Object to Array to display errors using Square API

Tags: php, arrays, json, payment-gateway

I'm currently implementing SquareUp Payment Method using their Connect V2 API. Processing the payment works fine however I would like to echo any errors to screen lets say for example if the card declines.

```
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r('<strong>Details:</strong><br/>');
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($e->getResponseBody());

  echo "</pre>";
}
```

When I dump the whole of `getResponseBody` I get the result below however I just want to dump the string in the 'detail' property. I thought that maybe converting to an array would help but honestly i'm not sure.

```
object(stdClass)#20 (1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#21 (3) {
      ["category"]=>
      string(20) "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"
      ["code"]=>
      string(13) "CARD_DECLINED"
      ["detail"]=>
      string(14) "Card declined."
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried doing this however it doesn't dump anything inside the `<pre></pre>` where as dumping the whole `$e->getResponseBody()` does output in `<pre></pre>`.

```
$json = file_get_contents($e->getResponseBody());
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->errors[0]->detail));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first resolve for `($obj->errors)` and then reference the array elements, like so:

```
<?php
$obj = (object)['errors' => [(object)['category' => 'PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR', 'code' => 'CARD_DECLINED', 'detail' => 'Card declined']]];

echo ($obj->errors)[0]->category;   // output PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR
echo '<br />';
echo ($obj->errors)[0]->code;       // output CARD_DECLINED
echo '<br />';
echo ($obj->errors)[0]->detail;     // output Card declined
?>
```

Comment: How do I get what you got in your `$obj`? The `detail` string may not always be `Card declined` therefore I can't just copy and paste your answer however not sure what to do here. Do I have to convert to array? if so how? Even just by copy and pasting your code error I get a HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: not sure I understand; you say: "however I just want to dump the string in the 'detail' property", so you do: `echo ($obj->errors)[0]->detail;` the result of the echo will obviously depend on what you got in the detail property.

Comment: Yes that is correct and I understand that however, how do I get the contents of what you have got in your $obj?

Comment: Ah I see now. It was as simple as this:
`$obj = $e->getResponseBody();
echo $obj->errors[0]->detail;     // output Card declined`

Comment: yep, you've nailed it